# Ghostable via Object Model

Tags: object-model, file, ghosting

Is it possible to set a file as Ghostable/GhostableInLibrary via the Server Object Model? I don't see any properties on `SPFile` that seem to fit the bill.

I know you can do this via an XML module, but I need to do it via the API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The SP Object Model does not support adding files pragmatically to SharePoint under Ghostable/GhostableInLibrary mode, therefore reflection is needed.

I found a good article with a code example:

http://erickhaw.blogspot.co.il/2012/02/create-pageitem-in-ghosted-mode.html